# How can I set up Windows 11 22H2 with a local account?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-account, bypass, windows-11-v22h2

After installing Windows 11 22H2, the wizard forces me to connect to the Internet and use a Microsoft Online Account. Is it possible to bypass it and use a local account?

Comment: @Ray Local account option is also available only in the Pro edition

Comment: Check this out: [How to Install Windows 11 Without an Internet Connection](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/install-windows-11-without-an-internet-connection/).

Answer (score 48):

Yes you can

When you reach the “Let’s Connect You To A Network” page, hit “Shift” and “F10” on the keyboard at the same time.

This will bring up the Command Prompt

In this new cmd  window, type in “taskmgr” and press “Enter” on the keyboard.
This will bring up the Task Manager window so you can see all running processes.
Expand the Task Manager by clicking the “More Details” button, and then find

“Network Connection Flow.”

Select this process and then hit the “End Task” button.

Now you can close the cmd and taskmgr windows and return to the Windows 11 setup, where you will enter a name for a local account.

***I found a slightly faster way, once cmd prompt is open type in

> OOBE\BYPASSNRO

hit enter and close cmd window, now you can enter a local user account name

Answer (score 9):

- Use the email address `no@thankyou.com`.
- Type any password (e.g. `123456`).
- The wizard says "Oops, something went wrong".
- Click `Next` to open a screen that allows you to create a local account.

[image]

Comment: ```thankyou.com``` is a registered domain. Using an email address of a domain you don't know, to even try to register windows is an exceptionally BAD idea from a security point of view !

Comment: Better to use example.com as that is guaranteed to be an example domain which will not process mail and which will error on HTTP requests.

Comment: @fooquency Still not guarenteed; it's a well-known fact that the domain indeed is reserved for special use but there's nothing (rules don't count; they can be broken) stopping whoever has access to it from setting up their own tenant.

Comment: @aytimothy The example domains are operated by ICANN. It is exceptionally unlikely they will abuse them. Far less likely than any other existing domain, anyways.

Comment: If ICANN is abusing domains, all bets are off anyway because they own `.` the domain all other domains are subdomains of.

Comment: more importantly, it's exceptionally easy for Windows to blacklist `example.com`. GitHub blacklists `example.com` domain for account registrations, for instance. A reasonably long keysmashed domain name (i.e. `lakshgjfkhqlerkjtl.com`) on any TLD would be a better bet - if NXDOMAIN gets you to the "oops" screen, that is.

Answer (score 7):

Below is not for updating from Windows 10/11, but for installing 22H2 from scratch, or performing clean install.

First, download the Windows 11 22H2's iso and [rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) that make a USB memory a bootable Windows installer. That sounds as same as just making it by yourself, but there's reason I recommend using rufus - It allows you to bypass the requirements of network and Microsoft account by just clicking one box.

When you start rufus, it shows the UI of the software. Pick your USB memory, and once you've selected your USB memory, then hit `SELECT` to select Windows 11's iso.

Once it's done, rufus automatically assumes you've selected Windows' iso. Hit `START`, and after that a box will show up.[image]

Tick the box that says **Remove requirement for an online Microsoft account**, and then hit `OK` (**Disable data collection** is optional, if you don't like the data collection then tick it).

That's it. When rufus completed flashing iso to the USB memory, restart your PC, boot from USB memory, start installing Windows normally. It will ask you to connect internet, but ignore it, and voila it won't ask you to login to Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to proceed and log in with a Microsoft account or create a new one.

Once you're in Windows then you can create a local admin account, log in to the local account, and delete the Microsoft account.

Comment: That's not a good solution. Your Windows' key will be linked to that account.

Comment: "It is essential that you link your Microsoft account to the Windows 11 license on your device. Linking your Microsoft account with your digital license enables you to reactivate Windows using the Activation troubleshooter whenever you make a significant hardware change." [...] "After your Microsoft account has been added, on the Activation page you’ll see Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your Microsoft account." | https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows-c39005d4-95ee-b91e-b399-2820fda32227