# Why is the user account type selection missing in my windows 11 setup

Tags: user-accounts, windows-11, windows-installation

I am trying to set up a new (used) PC with Win 11. I used the official media creation tool, created a usb-stick and started the setup.

At the point where (according to several online step-by-step guides) there should be the question if the computer is for private or business/school use, there is no such thing.
Instead I am directly on a screen where it asks me for a business or school account (which I don't have).

My guess is that (because I bought the pc used from a company that got rid of their old hardware) the PC is somehow recognized as a business-device.

The question is: how does the setup know this? Is this stored somewhere on the device (so I could simply fix this). I think it can't be on the harddrive, because I completely wiped it during the setup.
Or is there some "machine-id"/cloud-magic involved which the organization previously owning the device has to fix?

I already tried several guides I found online, but nothing worked. Things I've tried:

- disconnecting the device from the internet durig setup (just leads to an error message that requires me to connect to the internet again)
- Running oobe\bypassnro from the commandline (just leads to a reboot and ending up at the same login prompt)
- or killing certain oobe processes (only leads to the setup wizard restarting)

Comment: “My guess is that (because I bought the pc used from a company that got rid of their old hardware) the PC is somehow recognized as a business-device” - This absolutely is NOT happening. What edition of Windows 11 are you trying to install. [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: [OOBE\BYPASSNRO](https://www.neowin.net/news/here039s-how-you-can-setup-your-windows-11-device-without-an-internet-connection/) should be relevant. Possible duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1744963/how-can-i-set-up-windows-11-22h2-with-a-local-account/1745016#1745016). Likewise, legible screenshots, of what you do see might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set up Windows 11 22H2 with a local account?](https://superuser.com/questions/1744963/how-can-i-set-up-windows-11-22h2-with-a-local-account)

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you arrive at that screen :

- First try clicking the back arrow.
  If it lets you, then you should be able to setup your account.
  If not, follow below for a workaround.
- Click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
- Run the command `ncpa.cpl` to bring up your network adapters
- Disable your network adapter and close that window
- Now click the back arrow and setup a local account.

You could also try to disable the internet by disconnecting the cable,
so as to force an offline installation.