# Configure Windows 11 Home PC with Google Workspace accounts & Office 365 Business accounts

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-11, office365, google-workspace

Windows 11 Home apparently forbids you to use a Microsoft Work or School accounts to log in. You can circumvent by creating an additional Microsoft Personal account using the same email, but this solution is confusing my non-advanced users to handle 2 MS accounts with same id, different passwords, different features on the same computer.
How should I configure these PCs to provide simple log-in, simple access to Office 365 services, and simple access to email (through Google Workspace)?

More context :
I'm volunteering to help a small non-profit organization with their IT set-up. About 20 users, not too much money. They have :

- a domain name,
- a free Google Workspace offer (for non-profit, all 20 users have their emails / chat / calendar / smartphones with this Workspace account)
- a few free licenses for Office 365 business (for non-profits, less than 10 licenses, created via a Microsoft Work or School account)
- a few old computers that I configured with ChromeOS Flex (works great with all Google Workspace accounts).
- 3 new decent donated computers with Windows 11 Home.

W11Home apparently forces creating Microsoft Personal accounts for my users to log in W11, + their Microsoft Work or School accounts to log into Office 365, + their Google Workspace accounts to access their emails.
That's 3 accounts using the same id, 3 different passwords on the same computer, for users that are basically IT illiterate.  The mix-up of a MS personal and MS Work/School account on the same computer is especially confusing for them (for instance, it means they have 2 different "onedrive" folders to save their work).

The solution I found so far is to create local accounts on the W11Home PC to log-in. Users still have 3 accounts with 3 passwords to handle, but at least it avoids the mix-up between MS Personal and MS Work/School onedrive.

Another solution might be to upgrade the 3 W11Home to W11Pro, but that involves additional costs.

*[My first question in this community, hope it's in the right place and right format]*

Comment: "W11Home apparently forces creating Microsoft Personal accounts for my users to log in W11" - [You can bypass this requirement.](https://superuser.com/questions/1744963/how-can-i-set-up-windows-11-22h2-with-a-local-account) other than than I have never heard of linking a Windows account to a Google Workspace backend.

Comment: Microsoft has licensing programs for not for profits. You should look into these.

Comment: Further, we don't really answer licensing questions because we are not qualified to answer those.